# Django: match one or more from a set of keyworded regular expressions in an urlconf

Tags: python, regex, django, grouping, urlconf

I have a Django view that takes three optional keyworded arguments. I want to handle the regular expression for matching possible urls to this view in one line. I want to structure the urls nicely.

An example:
My possible parameters are start which is an int, serial which is a string of length 13, and end which is another int.

An url might look like:

```
/main/s20130509/e20130510/ABC1234567890
or
/main/s20130509/e20130510/
or 
/main/ABC1234567890
```

Where the e and s prefixed components are end and start respectively, and ABC1234567890 is serial.

I want to pull these end, start, serial values and pass them to the view as values start=s20130509, etc...

Right now I am doing this by exhaustively listing the permutations on separate lines, and it seems like there must be a better way.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
url(r'^base_url/(?P<serial>[^/]{13}|(?P<end>e\d{8})|(?P<start>s\d{8})/*$', view_method),
```

Basically, the logic of what I want to do is clear to me; I want to pull all instances of any of the three matches and pass them as keyworded params, but I can't find a resource to figure out the ReGex syntax to fit this.

Any thoughts? I'm happy to do pretty much whatever gets the job done elegantly.

Thanks for your time,

Tim

Comment: It gets very confusing. Dont do it in one line. Have the URLs match in separate targets

Comment: That feels really bad. I'm repeating 6 lines of urls even if I forcibly order the different args in the app. This particular set of inputs is something several of my views need to accept, so I'm potentially having 12-18 redundant lines of mappings. I'd love it if someone would humor me and describe how to do this with one expression, then let me/future finders of this post decide if it's worth the complexity.

Comment: Found a similar thread. The two solutions advocated there are hard coding the urls, or parsing along "/" then having the view handle the more complex logic. I feel there is a better solution.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432363/django-variable-parameters-in-urlconf?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're wanting is:

```
url(r'^base_url/(?P<serial>[^/]{13}/$', view_method),
```

with the addition of optional groups for the `end` and `start` kwargs, so:

```
# Optional, non-capturing group surrounding the named group for each (so you don't have to capture the slashes or the "e" or "s"
(?:e(?P<end>\d{8})/)
```

Then, allow up to 2 of those, in either order:

```
((?:s(?P<start>\d{8})/)|(?:e(?P<end>\d{8})/)){0,2}
```

The result is:

```
url(r'^base_url/((?:s(?P<start>\d{8})/)|(?:e(?P<end>\d{8})/)){0,2}(?P<serial>[^/]{13})/$', view_method),
```

Disclaimer, I wrote this in this box, so it'll take me a moment to test it and update the answer (if it's wrong).

### Update:

Indeed, it worked :) I matched the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/base_url/e77777777/s88888888/1234567890123/
http://127.0.0.1:8080/base_url/s88888888/e77777777/1234567890123/
http://127.0.0.1:8080/base_url/s88888888/1234567890123/
http://127.0.0.1:8080/base_url/e77777777/1234567890123/
http://127.0.0.1:8080/base_url/1234567890123/
```

The kwargs looked like this (raised in an exception from the `get` method of a sub-class of `View` when requested with all three segments - the end and/or start were `None` when left out):

```
{'start': u'88888888', 'serial': u'1234567890123', 'end': u'77777777'}
```

Comment: Orokusaki, this is exactly what I want to do. I'll check this out. Part of my motivation here was thinking that this situation will come up a lot in the future, so I appreciate the answer. Acceptance pending fiddling!

Comment: Accepted, Thanks. I especially appreciate the recognition of what I was trying to do and inclusion of the non-capturing component in an outer-group. I didn't know about that and will find it pretty handy.

Comment: @TimWilder -  no prob. I'm glad that's what you were looking for.